# How to get last promise response if we have multiple api's call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, axios, fetch

I have an array of data , I am using for loop to send these data to server . Let suppose if we have 3 elements in array . It will call 3 api's at same time but what I want to achieve is to be get last promise resolve response, For example 3 files have 3 different size Ist two files are in small size and 3rd file size is large it make sense 3rd file will take some time when large file size promise get resolved I want to console that response.  I really tried hard but didn't find any solution could someone please help me .

```
for (let i = 0; i < selectedFiles.length; i++) {
      let bodyFormData = new FormData()
      bodyFormData.append('file', selectedFiles[i])

      const options = {
        onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
          const { loaded, total } = progressEvent
          let percent = Math.floor((loaded * 100) / total)


          selectedFiles[i].percentage = percent

          this.setState({
            progressInfos: selectedFiles,
          })
        },
      }

      axios
        .post(`${config.apiPath}/api/fileUpload`, bodyFormData, options)
        .then((res) => {
        })
    }
```

Comment: You need to use `Promise.all`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```js
let promises = [];
for (let i = 0; i < selectedFiles.length; i++) {
  /*...*/
  p.push(axios.post(`${config.apiPath}/api/fileUpload`, bodyFormData, options));
  /*...*/
}
Promise.all(p).then((res) => {
  console.log(res); // res[0], res[1], res[...n]
});
```